# How does tf.nn.dilation2d compute gradient and learn its filters

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I want to understand how the tf.nn.dilation2d is working and how the "filters", which refers to a structural element are learned.

The official documentation is available here : https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dilation2d

The documentation didn't reference a scientific paper, and I found a lot of different idea in scientific literature, about morphological filters in deep learnign. Here just some examples :

- https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.01751
- https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.01532
- https://doi.org/10.1109/TNNLS.2018.2890334
- https://doi.org/10.1142/S0218001419540247

I searched into the code (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.0/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L327-L392), but the tf.nn.dilation2d only call gen_nn_ops.dilation2d

```
@tf_export("nn.dilation2d", v1=[])
@dispatch.add_dispatch_support
def dilation2d_v2(input, filters, strides, padding, data_format, dilations, name=None):
  if data_format != "NHWC":
    raise ValueError("Data formats other than NHWC are not yet supported")
  return gen_nn_ops.dilation2d(input=input,
                               filter=filters,
                               strides=strides,
                               rates=dilations,
                               padding=padding,
                               name=name)
```

I searched into gen_nn_ops.py (which I found inside my python lib folder, probably because it's generated from somewhere else) but I didn't understand what the code is doing.

```
def dilation2d(input, filter, strides, rates, padding, name=None):
  r"""Computes the grayscale dilation of 4-D `input` and 3-D `filter` tensors.

  The `input` tensor has shape `[batch, in_height, in_width, depth]` and the
  `filter` tensor has shape `[filter_height, filter_width, depth]`, i.e., each
  input channel is processed independently of the others with its own structuring
  function. The `output` tensor has shape
  `[batch, out_height, out_width, depth]`. The spatial dimensions of the output
  tensor depend on the `padding` algorithm. We currently only support the default
  "NHWC" `data_format`.

  In detail, the grayscale morphological 2-D dilation is the max-sum correlation
  (for consistency with `conv2d`, we use unmirrored filters):

      output[b, y, x, c] =
         max_{dy, dx} input[b,
                            strides[1] * y + rates[1] * dy,
                            strides[2] * x + rates[2] * dx,
                            c] +
                      filter[dy, dx, c]

  Max-pooling is a special case when the filter has size equal to the pooling
  kernel size and contains all zeros.

  Note on duality: The dilation of `input` by the `filter` is equal to the
  negation of the erosion of `-input` by the reflected `filter`.

  Args:
    input: A `Tensor`. Must be one of the following types: `float32`, `float64`, `int32`, `uint8`, `int16`, `int8`, `int64`, `bfloat16`, `uint16`, `half`, `uint32`, `uint64`.
      4-D with shape `[batch, in_height, in_width, depth]`.
    filter: A `Tensor`. Must have the same type as `input`.
      3-D with shape `[filter_height, filter_width, depth]`.
    strides: A list of `ints` that has length `>= 4`.
      The stride of the sliding window for each dimension of the input
      tensor. Must be: `[1, stride_height, stride_width, 1]`.
    rates: A list of `ints` that has length `>= 4`.
      The input stride for atrous morphological dilation. Must be:
      `[1, rate_height, rate_width, 1]`.
    padding: A `string` from: `"SAME", "VALID"`.
      The type of padding algorithm to use.
    name: A name for the operation (optional).

  Returns:
    A `Tensor`. Has the same type as `input`.
  """
  _ctx = _context._context or _context.context()
  tld = _ctx._thread_local_data
  if tld.is_eager:
    try:
      _result = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_FastPathExecute(
        _ctx._context_handle, tld.device_name, "Dilation2D", name,
        tld.op_callbacks, input, filter, "strides", strides, "rates", rates,
        "padding", padding)
      return _result
    except _core._FallbackException:
      try:
        return dilation2d_eager_fallback(
            input, filter, strides=strides, rates=rates, padding=padding,
            name=name, ctx=_ctx)
      except _core._SymbolicException:
        pass  # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
    except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
      _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
  if not isinstance(strides, (list, tuple)):
    raise TypeError(
        "Expected list for 'strides' argument to "
        "'dilation2d' Op, not %r." % strides)
  strides = [_execute.make_int(_i, "strides") for _i in strides]
  if not isinstance(rates, (list, tuple)):
    raise TypeError(
        "Expected list for 'rates' argument to "
        "'dilation2d' Op, not %r." % rates)
  rates = [_execute.make_int(_i, "rates") for _i in rates]
  padding = _execute.make_str(padding, "padding")
  _, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(
        "Dilation2D", input=input, filter=filter, strides=strides,
                      rates=rates, padding=padding, name=name)
  _result = _outputs[:]
  if _execute.must_record_gradient():
    _attrs = ("T", _op._get_attr_type("T"), "strides",
              _op.get_attr("strides"), "rates", _op.get_attr("rates"),
              "padding", _op.get_attr("padding"))
    _inputs_flat = _op.inputs
    _execute.record_gradient(
        "Dilation2D", _inputs_flat, _attrs, _result)
  _result, = _result
  return _result

Dilation2D = tf_export("raw_ops.Dilation2D")(_ops.to_raw_op(dilation2d))


def dilation2d_eager_fallback(input, filter, strides, rates, padding, name, ctx):
  if not isinstance(strides, (list, tuple)):
    raise TypeError(
        "Expected list for 'strides' argument to "
        "'dilation2d' Op, not %r." % strides)
  strides = [_execute.make_int(_i, "strides") for _i in strides]
  if not isinstance(rates, (list, tuple)):
    raise TypeError(
        "Expected list for 'rates' argument to "
        "'dilation2d' Op, not %r." % rates)
  rates = [_execute.make_int(_i, "rates") for _i in rates]
  padding = _execute.make_str(padding, "padding")
  _attr_T, _inputs_T = _execute.args_to_matching_eager([input, filter], ctx)
  (input, filter) = _inputs_T
  _inputs_flat = [input, filter]
  _attrs = ("T", _attr_T, "strides", strides, "rates", rates, "padding",
  padding)
  _result = _execute.execute(b"Dilation2D", 1, inputs=_inputs_flat,
                             attrs=_attrs, ctx=ctx, name=name)
  if _execute.must_record_gradient():
    _execute.record_gradient(
        "Dilation2D", _inputs_flat, _attrs, _result)
  _result, = _result
  return _result


def dilation2d_backprop_filter(input, filter, out_backprop, strides, rates, padding, name=None):
  r"""Computes the gradient of morphological 2-D dilation with respect to the filter.

  Args:
    input: A `Tensor`. Must be one of the following types: `float32`, `float64`, `int32`, `uint8`, `int16`, `int8`, `int64`, `bfloat16`, `uint16`, `half`, `uint32`, `uint64`.
      4-D with shape `[batch, in_height, in_width, depth]`.
    filter: A `Tensor`. Must have the same type as `input`.
      3-D with shape `[filter_height, filter_width, depth]`.
    out_backprop: A `Tensor`. Must have the same type as `input`.
      4-D with shape `[batch, out_height, out_width, depth]`.
    strides: A list of `ints` that has length `>= 4`.
      1-D of length 4. The stride of the sliding window for each dimension of
      the input tensor. Must be: `[1, stride_height, stride_width, 1]`.
    rates: A list of `ints` that has length `>= 4`.
      1-D of length 4. The input stride for atrous morphological dilation.
      Must be: `[1, rate_height, rate_width, 1]`.
    padding: A `string` from: `"SAME", "VALID"`.
      The type of padding algorithm to use.
    name: A name for the operation (optional).

  Returns:
    A `Tensor`. Has the same type as `input`.
  """
  _ctx = _context._context or _context.context()
  tld = _ctx._thread_local_data
  if tld.is_eager:
    try:
      _result = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_FastPathExecute(
        _ctx._context_handle, tld.device_name, "Dilation2DBackpropFilter",
        name, tld.op_callbacks, input, filter, out_backprop, "strides",
        strides, "rates", rates, "padding", padding)
      return _result
    except _core._FallbackException:
      try:
        return dilation2d_backprop_filter_eager_fallback(
            input, filter, out_backprop, strides=strides, rates=rates,
            padding=padding, name=name, ctx=_ctx)
      except _core._SymbolicException:
        pass  # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
    except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
      _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
  if not isinstance(strides, (list, tuple)):
    raise TypeError(
        "Expected list for 'strides' argument to "
        "'dilation2d_backprop_filter' Op, not %r." % strides)
  strides = [_execute.make_int(_i, "strides") for _i in strides]
  if not isinstance(rates, (list, tuple)):
    raise TypeError(
        "Expected list for 'rates' argument to "
        "'dilation2d_backprop_filter' Op, not %r." % rates)
  rates = [_execute.make_int(_i, "rates") for _i in rates]
  padding = _execute.make_str(padding, "padding")
  _, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(
        "Dilation2DBackpropFilter", input=input, filter=filter,
                                    out_backprop=out_backprop,
                                    strides=strides, rates=rates,
                                    padding=padding, name=name)
  _result = _outputs[:]
  if _execute.must_record_gradient():
    _attrs = ("T", _op._get_attr_type("T"), "strides",
              _op.get_attr("strides"), "rates", _op.get_attr("rates"),
              "padding", _op.get_attr("padding"))
    _inputs_flat = _op.inputs
    _execute.record_gradient(
        "Dilation2DBackpropFilter", _inputs_flat, _attrs, _result)
  _result, = _result
  return _result

Dilation2DBackpropFilter = tf_export("raw_ops.Dilation2DBackpropFilter")(_ops.to_raw_op(dilation2d_backprop_filter))


def dilation2d_backprop_filter_eager_fallback(input, filter, out_backprop, strides, rates, padding, name, ctx):
  if not isinstance(strides, (list, tuple)):
    raise TypeError(
        "Expected list for 'strides' argument to "
        "'dilation2d_backprop_filter' Op, not %r." % strides)
  strides = [_execute.make_int(_i, "strides") for _i in strides]
  if not isinstance(rates, (list, tuple)):
    raise TypeError(
        "Expected list for 'rates' argument to "
        "'dilation2d_backprop_filter' Op, not %r." % rates)
  rates = [_execute.make_int(_i, "rates") for _i in rates]
  padding = _execute.make_str(padding, "padding")
  _attr_T, _inputs_T = _execute.args_to_matching_eager([input, filter, out_backprop], ctx)
  (input, filter, out_backprop) = _inputs_T
  _inputs_flat = [input, filter, out_backprop]
  _attrs = ("T", _attr_T, "strides", strides, "rates", rates, "padding",
  padding)
  _result = _execute.execute(b"Dilation2DBackpropFilter", 1,
                             inputs=_inputs_flat, attrs=_attrs, ctx=ctx,
                             name=name)
  if _execute.must_record_gradient():
    _execute.record_gradient(
        "Dilation2DBackpropFilter", _inputs_flat, _attrs, _result)
  _result, = _result
  return _result


def dilation2d_backprop_input(input, filter, out_backprop, strides, rates, padding, name=None):
  r"""Computes the gradient of morphological 2-D dilation with respect to the input.

  Args:
    input: A `Tensor`. Must be one of the following types: `float32`, `float64`, `int32`, `uint8`, `int16`, `int8`, `int64`, `bfloat16`, `uint16`, `half`, `uint32`, `uint64`.
      4-D with shape `[batch, in_height, in_width, depth]`.
    filter: A `Tensor`. Must have the same type as `input`.
      3-D with shape `[filter_height, filter_width, depth]`.
    out_backprop: A `Tensor`. Must have the same type as `input`.
      4-D with shape `[batch, out_height, out_width, depth]`.
    strides: A list of `ints` that has length `>= 4`.
      1-D of length 4. The stride of the sliding window for each dimension of
      the input tensor. Must be: `[1, stride_height, stride_width, 1]`.
    rates: A list of `ints` that has length `>= 4`.
      1-D of length 4. The input stride for atrous morphological dilation.
      Must be: `[1, rate_height, rate_width, 1]`.
    padding: A `string` from: `"SAME", "VALID"`.
      The type of padding algorithm to use.
    name: A name for the operation (optional).

  Returns:
    A `Tensor`. Has the same type as `input`.
  """
  _ctx = _context._context or _context.context()
  tld = _ctx._thread_local_data
  if tld.is_eager:
    try:
      _result = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_FastPathExecute(
        _ctx._context_handle, tld.device_name, "Dilation2DBackpropInput",
        name, tld.op_callbacks, input, filter, out_backprop, "strides",
        strides, "rates", rates, "padding", padding)
      return _result
    except _core._FallbackException:
      try:
        return dilation2d_backprop_input_eager_fallback(
            input, filter, out_backprop, strides=strides, rates=rates,
            padding=padding, name=name, ctx=_ctx)
      except _core._SymbolicException:
        pass  # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
    except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
      _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.
  if not isinstance(strides, (list, tuple)):
    raise TypeError(
        "Expected list for 'strides' argument to "
        "'dilation2d_backprop_input' Op, not %r." % strides)
  strides = [_execute.make_int(_i, "strides") for _i in strides]
  if not isinstance(rates, (list, tuple)):
    raise TypeError(
        "Expected list for 'rates' argument to "
        "'dilation2d_backprop_input' Op, not %r." % rates)
  rates = [_execute.make_int(_i, "rates") for _i in rates]
  padding = _execute.make_str(padding, "padding")
  _, _, _op, _outputs = _op_def_library._apply_op_helper(
        "Dilation2DBackpropInput", input=input, filter=filter,
                                   out_backprop=out_backprop, strides=strides,
                                   rates=rates, padding=padding, name=name)
  _result = _outputs[:]
  if _execute.must_record_gradient():
    _attrs = ("T", _op._get_attr_type("T"), "strides",
              _op.get_attr("strides"), "rates", _op.get_attr("rates"),
              "padding", _op.get_attr("padding"))
    _inputs_flat = _op.inputs
    _execute.record_gradient(
        "Dilation2DBackpropInput", _inputs_flat, _attrs, _result)
  _result, = _result
  return _result

Dilation2DBackpropInput = tf_export("raw_ops.Dilation2DBackpropInput")(_ops.to_raw_op(dilation2d_backprop_input))


def dilation2d_backprop_input_eager_fallback(input, filter, out_backprop, strides, rates, padding, name, ctx):
  if not isinstance(strides, (list, tuple)):
    raise TypeError(
        "Expected list for 'strides' argument to "
        "'dilation2d_backprop_input' Op, not %r." % strides)
  strides = [_execute.make_int(_i, "strides") for _i in strides]
  if not isinstance(rates, (list, tuple)):
    raise TypeError(
        "Expected list for 'rates' argument to "
        "'dilation2d_backprop_input' Op, not %r." % rates)
  rates = [_execute.make_int(_i, "rates") for _i in rates]
  padding = _execute.make_str(padding, "padding")
  _attr_T, _inputs_T = _execute.args_to_matching_eager([input, filter, out_backprop], ctx)
  (input, filter, out_backprop) = _inputs_T
  _inputs_flat = [input, filter, out_backprop]
  _attrs = ("T", _attr_T, "strides", strides, "rates", rates, "padding",
  padding)
  _result = _execute.execute(b"Dilation2DBackpropInput", 1,
                             inputs=_inputs_flat, attrs=_attrs, ctx=ctx,
                             name=name)
  if _execute.must_record_gradient():
    _execute.record_gradient(
        "Dilation2DBackpropInput", _inputs_flat, _attrs, _result)
  _result, = _result
  return _result
```

Thank you for your time.